# For loops in nested list with variable numbers of indices

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a nested list, where the outside list has 41 elements, and each of those elements are list, each with a different number of elements inside them.

I want to be able to go through every element in the nested lists and add 41 empty lists, making a three-tier nested list. I tried to do that with this code:

```
for x in reflist:
    for y in reflist[x]:
        for z in range(0, 41):
            reflist[x][y].append([])
```

but it doesn't work because values used in lines 2 and 4 (`x` and `y`) are lists, not integers.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: `x` is bound to each successive element in `reflist`, **not** an index. The next loop would be `for y in x:`, therefor.

Comment: The innermost line would also need correcting to `y.append([])` for the same reasons.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that works with line 2, but what do I then do about line 4? I'm getting the same error message that list indices must be integers.

Comment: Again, that's because `x` and `y` are not integers, they are the actual elements. If `reflist` is a list of lists, then `x` is bound to each of those nested lists, one by one. `for y in x` then binds `y` to the  elements in those nested lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python `for` loop does not produce indices, it loops over the elements of the iterable **directly**. `x` is bound to each element in `reflist`, not to an index, so `reflist[x]` is trying to index the list with the elements. That won't work unless your list directly contains integers that are all valid indices too.

Just use `x` and `y` directly:

```
for x in reflist:
    for y in x:
        for z in range(0, 41):
            y.append([])
```

You can reduce that to:

```
for x in reflist:
    for y in x:
        y.extend([] for _ in range(41))
```